# where does top gets real-time data

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, pid, top-command

Where does `top` application gets it's data on Linux? I would be interested in real-time CPU load/pid data.(I read allmost all documentation in /proc/pid man page, but the info isn't there).

The pid is a jboss. I need the data lightweight (to be exported easily).

Comment: Load is a system wide metric, not a process one. Did you mean process CPU usage?

Comment: are you sure the info isn't there? 'find /proc/1' for example, there's a LOT of stuff, did you go through it all?

Comment: @Xander, apparently not, because that is, in fact, where top gets its data ... :)

Comment: @bdonlan there is no /proc/pid/stat field for cpu usage. the data must come from some calculation/aggregation of that file's data. but, what's the algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented in [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc), in the file `/proc/(pid)/stat` you have the fields:

> ```
> utime %lu
> ```
>
> Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in
>   user mode, measured in clock ticks
>   (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).  This
>   includes guest time, guest_time (time
>   spent running a virtual CPU, see
>   below), so that applications that are
>   not aware of the guest time field do
>   not lose that time  from  their
>   calculations.
>
> ```
> stime %lu
> ```
>
> Amount of time that this
>   process has been scheduled in kernel
>   mode, measured in clock ticks (divide
>   by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).

To get CPU usage for a specific process, use those fields. The toplevel process will aggregate CPU usage over all threads; for a per-thread breakdown, you can find the other threads in `/proc/(pid)/task`.

If you would prefer to be notified when CPU time exceeds some threshold, you can use [clock_getcpuclockid](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/clock_getcpuclockid.3.html) to get a handle to its cpu time clock, then [timer_create](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) or [timerfd](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) to be notified when it hits a specified level. However, note that cross-process cputime timers are an optional feature in the POSIX specification and may not be supported (I've not tested).

Comment: actually I belive "ps -Lp(pid) opcpu" does aggregate all that threads, isn't it? Unfortunately ps gives just snapshots of that cpu/thread load (it can't be used in real-time monitoring), and aggregating in the bash script all 300 threads in that jboss, by "cat"-ing all the file specific for that child pids it looks kind of unreliable.

Comment: @Xander, after checking, it turns out the toplevel process aggregates over all threads. So you can just use the stat file for monitoring. I've also added some notes on clock_getcpuclockid, which can be helpful as well.

Answer (score 12):

If in doubt, use strace(1)!

```
open("/proc/2/stat", O_RDONLY)    = 4
open("/proc/2/statm", O_RDONLY)   = 4
open("/proc/3/stat", O_RDONLY)    = 4
open("/proc/3/statm", O_RDONLY)   = 4
```

Comment: hi, thanks for strace hint! it's great. the only issue is that following a strace dump I can't get where it actually write to the stdout the cpu load (because analyzing the files you recommended I could't find what I was searching...)