# How does the top command name the process that is being executed

Tags: linux, unix, top-command

How does top name the command that is being executed I mean the last field of the command.

How does it name the command (like eclipse,java etc.) , are there any other commands which show the same not like **`ps`** command which shows the complete process command( last field of **`ps`** /bin/shared/eclipse ).

I have already gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827077/) but it didn't explain it though.

Comment: No, it depends on the option you use with `ps`. Anyway, what you're looking for highly depends on the OS... There is no generic technic to extract processes info. On some Unixes there is a special procfs that uniformize the parsing of the process table...

Comment: Thanks Jean.. So you mean to say that top gets some if its info from process table and some from /proc ?

Comment: Exactly there is no other way if you want to have some precise info about processes.